# Ansible: Check if my user exists on remote host, else use root user to connect with ssh

Tags: ssh, ansible

I'm currently writting an Ansible script which should update openssl on every host running Debian or CentOS. On the hosts our SSH-Keys are deposited for my own user *or* root. I want to check if my user is existing on the host, if not I want to authenticate with the root user. Is there a possibility to do this? I tried it with a bash command but I want to check if my user exists *before* I'm running the tasks. Maybe there are other solutions to my problem but I don't know them. Running this playbook throws a syntax error. My Script looks like this right now:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ host_group }}" 
  remote_user: "{{ username }}"
  tasks:

# Check whether there's a existinig user or whether you have to use root
    - name: Check whether there's your user on the machine
      action: shell /usr/bin/getent passwd $username | /usr/bin/wc -l | tr -d ''
      register: user_exist
      remote_user: root
      when: user_exist.stdout == 0
      tags:
         - users

# Install openssl on Ubuntu or Debian
    - name: Install openssl on Ubuntu or Debian
      become: True
      become_user: root
      apt: name=openssl state=latest
      when: ansible_distribution == 'Debian' or ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'

# Install openssl on CentOS or RHEL
    - name: Install openssl on CentOS or RHEL
      become: True
      become_user: root
      yum: name=openssl state=latest
      when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can test the connection with `local_action` first.
Ansible need to know how to connect to the host for sure, otherwise it will trigger `host unreachable` error and skip remaining tasks for that host.
Something like this:

```
- hosts: myservers
  gather_facts: no  # or it will fail on the setup step
  tasks:
    - name: Test user
      local_action: "command ssh -q -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=3 {{ inventory_hostname }} 'echo ok'"
      register: test_user
      ignore_errors: true
      changed_when: false

    - name: Do useful stuff
      remote_user: "{{ test_user | success | ternary(omit, 'root') }}"
      command: echo ok
```

Comment: Can you explain what this code does? I want to understand the sense of it and don't want to copy and paste this without knowledge

Comment: Hmm... What part? At first, we execute `ssh` command on localhost to test if it is possible to connect to host in question with current user. Register results to `test_user` variable. Ignore errors if any (because command will fail if we can't connect with current user). Then we set `remote_user` for subsequent task to `root` based on the success/failure of our test: if `success` (current user exists), don't set `remote_user` (use `omit` keyword); if `failure` (current user doesn't exists), set `remote_user` to `root`.

Comment: Cool, this works! The gather_facts: no above disables the gathering of facts about the OS on the remote hosts, but I need to know which os is running on the remote host for the package managers. How can I gather the remote OS without gathering every fact? EDIT: Just for me to know, can you explain the 'ternary' thing that you wrote?

Comment: Run `setup` module as the first task after user check – this will force fact gathering.

Answer (score 8):

A more native and elegant way to test your SSH connection is with the Ansible [ping](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ping_module.html) module (which verifies the end-to-end SSH connection, *not* ICMP), and to use the playbook keyword [`ignore_unreachable`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html), which was added in Ansible 2.7.

The technique below puts SSH testing into its own play where facts are not gathered; subsequent plays will gather facts as normal:

```yaml
---
###
## First play: Dynamically configure SSH user
##
- hosts: "{{ host_group }}"
  gather_facts: false  # don't try to ssh yet!!
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_user: "{{ username }}"

  tasks:
    - name: "Test SSH connection"
      ping:  # <-- no args needed
      ignore_unreachable: true
      ignore_errors: true
      changed_when: false
      register: ssh_test

    - name: "Fall back to root user?"
      when: ssh_test.unreachable is defined
      connection: local
      set_fact:
        ansible_ssh_user: root


###
## Next play: Install Stuff
###
- hosts: "{{ host_group }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Install openssl on Ubuntu or Debian
      # ...
```

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work without having the unreachable=1 in the play recap the first time running the playbook?